# Arithmetic expressions in Tcl, Perl

Tags: perl, tcl

I am converting a Perl code to tcl. Have completed most of it but stuck in some logical and mathematical expressions. Sought your help:

Line1:

```
my $value = read_phy($phy, 0) | (0x1 << 15);
```

Line2: ( a bit similar to previous one)

```
my $value = (read_phy($phy, 23) & ~0x0700) | (0x00 << 8);
```

For line 1, after many trials, I thought to break the logic in two statements but still unable to clean the compilation:

```
    set temp_value  [phy_rd $devno 0] 
    set value [$temp_value | (0x1 << 15)]
```

Line 3:

```
$regvalue &= ~0x0C000
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: a function with two arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`expr` command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) for math:

1

```tcl
# my $value = read_phy($phy, 0) | (0x1 << 15);
set value [expr {[phy_rd $phy 0] | (0x1 << 15)}]
```

2

```tcl
# my $value = (read_phy($phy, 23) & ~0x0700) | (0x00 << 8); 
set value [expr { ([phy_rd $phy 23] & ~0x0700) | (0x00 << 8)}]
```

3

```tcl
# $regvalue &= ~0x0C000  
set regvalue [expr {$regvalue & ~0x0C000}]
```

Please also read [Brace your expr-essions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225)

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn !!